# Why is my return function not working the way I want it to? (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, printing, return

Can someone give me some hints or ideas as to why this:

```
def fishstore(fish, price):
  total = "Your", fish, "costs", price, "$"
  return total
print (fishstore("sardines", 5))
```

shows this:

```
('Your', 'sardines', 'costs', 5, '$')
```

instead of this:

```
Your sardines costs 5 $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a tuple, and that's what is being printed. Just because you return multiple items separate by commas does not mean `print()` will see those as separate arguments. Otherwise, how would you print a tuple as a tuple?

If you wanted to print the *contents* of the tuple as separate arguments, use the `*argument` call syntax:

```
print(*fishstore("sardines", 5))
```

The `*argument` syntax makes it explicit you want to unpack all the values into separate items for `print()` to process.

The function isn't all that useful, really. It might be more useful to use [*string formatting*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) to put the item and price together into a single string to print:

```
def fishstore(fish, price):
    total = "Your {} costs {}$".format(fish, price)
    return total
```

at which point `print(fishstore("sardines", 5))` will work just fine.

If you are using Python 3.6 (or newer), you can use the [`f'....'` formated string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) syntax too:

```
def fishstore(fish, price):
    total = f"Your {fish} costs {price}$"
    return total
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! I just have one more question: what do you mean by "the argument call syntax"?thank you!! I'm just beginning with python 3, so sorry if I ask stupid questions.

Comment: @MacKenzieRichards: Adding `(...)` after a name is called a [*call*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls). Part of that syntax is the ability to specify that an object should not be treated as a single argument to the call, but as a sequence of separate arguments.

Comment: @MacKenzieRichards: so `print(1, 2, 3)` can also be expressed as `args = [1, 2, 3]`, and `print(*args)`. Using `*args` in the `print` call tells Python to take all the elements contained in `args` and use those as separate arguments instead.

Comment: Ohhh! Thank you, I think I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

You can just concat the string by coding `total = "Your " + fish + "costs " + price +"$"` in replacement. I'm not too positive why it outputs it in a list like that, but the rest of the code looks correct. You could also just do `print ("Your %s cost %d $", fish, price)`.

In Python, commas don't concat. If you wanted it to be stored in a list, you could also use the .join() function as others have commented.